# How do you combine lifetimes in rust?

Tags: rust

This code:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
  value: Option<&'a int>,
  parent: Option<&'a Foo<'a>>
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
  fn bar<'a, 'b, 'c: 'a + 'b>(&'a self, other:&'b int) -> Foo<'c> {
    return Foo { value: Some(other), parent: Some(self) };
  }
}

fn main() {
  let e = 100i;
  {
    let f = Foo { value: None, parent: None };
    let g:Foo;
    {
       g = f.bar(&e);
    }
    // <--- g should be valid here
  }
  // 'a of f is now expired, so g should not be valid here.

  let f2 = Foo { value: None, parent: None };
  {
    let e2 = 100i;
    let g:Foo;
    {
       g = f2.bar(&e2);
    }
    // <--- g should be valid here
  }
  // 'b of e2 is now expired, so g should not be valid here.
}
```

Fails to compile with the error:

```
<anon>:8:30: 8:35 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
<anon>:8     return Foo { value: Some(other), parent: Some(self) };
                                      ^~~~~
<anon>:7:3: 9:4 note: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn bar<'a, 'b>(&'a self, other: &'b int) -> Foo<'b>
<anon>:7   fn bar<'a, 'b, 'c: 'a + 'b>(&'a self, other:&'b int) -> Foo<'c> {
<anon>:8     return Foo { value: Some(other), parent: Some(self) };
<anon>:9   }
```

(playpen: http://is.gd/vAvNFi )

This is obviously a contrived example, but it is something I want to do occasionally.

So...

1) How do you combine lifetimes? (ie. Return a Foo which has a lifetime of at least 'a or 'b, which ever is shorter)

2) Is there some way to write tests to asset lifetime compile failures?
(eg. try to compile a #[test] that uses the function in the wrong way and fails with a lifetime error)

Comment: (BTW, the code in the post doesn't compile, and doesn't match the code in the playpen link.)

Comment: @dbaupp my bad. Fixed now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The bounds `'c: 'a + 'b` means that `'c` is at least as long as `'a` and as long as `'b`. However, in this case, the `Foo` value is valid for exactly the shortest of `'a` and `'b`: as soon as the data behind either reference goes out of scope the whole `Foo` must be invalidated. (This is saying that data that is valid for `'c` is valid in the *union* of `'a` and `'b`.)

In more concrete terms, say `'b = 'static`, then `'c: 'a + 'static` means that `'c` must also be `'static`, so the return value would be `Foo<'static>`. This is clearly not right as it would be "upgrading" the limited `'a` `self` reference into one that lasts forever.

The correct behaviour here is taking the intersection of the lifetimes: the `Foo` is only valid while both function parameters are valid. The intersection operation is just labelling the references with the same name:

```
fn bar<'a>(&'a self, other: &'a int) -> Foo<'a>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to replace "largest" (union) with "smallest" (intersection). But, since bar is a method here, wouldn't it be better to omit the `'a` lifetime parameter on the method and use the `'a` from the `impl` instead? I know it causes errors when implementing a trait (the lifetime parameters must match those defined in the trait), but this is just a simple `impl`, so both options work.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: At least I agree with you. There seems to be no need for any new lifetime parameters for the function.

Answer (score 4):

Remove all the limetime parameters on `bar` and use the `'a` lifetime parameter from the `impl` instead.

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
  fn bar(&'a self, other:&'a int) -> Foo<'a> {                  // '
    return Foo { value: Some(other), parent: Some(self) };
  }
}
```

`'a` will be inferred by the compiler to be the smallest lifetime in which all references are valid.